# Maven to SVN repository

Tags: maven-3

I am trying to connect maven to SVN repository using valid credentials. My pom.xml file is as follows,

```
        <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.maven.myfirstproject</groupId>
<artifactId>myfirstproject</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<build>
 <scm>
 <connection>scm:svn:http://d-113017553/svn/PRONTO/trunk/dev</connection>
 <developerConnection>scm:svn:http://d-113017553/svn/PRONTO/trunk/dev</developerConnection>
</scm>

<servers>
 <id>central</id>
 <username>keerthana</username>
 <password>keerthana</password>
 <url>http://d-113017553/svn/PRONTO/trunk/dev</url>
</servers>
<plugin>
<groupid>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupid>
<artifactid>maven-scm-plugin</artifactid>
<version>1.8.1</version>
</plugin>
</build>
</project>
```

When i run it i get the following errors,

**1)coreException : could not calculate build plan: plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler:2.3.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved:Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:2.3.2

2)Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration:org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile(execution:default-testCompile,phase:test-compile)**

Would anyone help me out to solve the above errors pls?????

Comment: It sound like having problems accessing maven central or a repository at all? Behind a proxy?

Answer (score 0):

First your pom.xml file can contain the information about [VCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) but you have to follow the schema for the pom.xml file which can get a good impression about [here](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html).

Furthermore it's good practice to indent XML file correctly like this:

```
  <scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:http://svn.server.com/svn/my-project/trunk</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://svn.server.com/svn/my-project/trunk</developerConnection>
    <url>http://svn.server.com/websvn/my-project</url>
  </scm>
```

Apart from the above the things like this:

```
<servers>
 <id>central</id>
 <username>keerthana</username>
 <password>keerthana</password>
 <url>http://d-113017553/svn/PRONTO/trunk/dev</url>
</servers>
```

do not belong into the pom.xml. They should be put into the [setting.xml](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html) file in your home folder (usually $HOME/.m2/settings.xml). And of course should you never put credentials into your pom file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am getting Build success message in the console now. But i don think that it's connecting to SVN. The messages in the console are as follows,

Comment: I am not able to copy all the messages here. Can anyone please tell me where can i check whether its connected to SVN or not?